# How to 'declare' variables for multi-thread usage?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

On an interview the other day I was asked how to 'declare' variables in order to use them across threads. Thankfully the interview went quite well and I got the job, but I'm still stumped on this one... and even wondering if the interviewer might not have quite asked the question he really intended.

I think he might have either been thinking about what the ThreadStatic attribute does, or possibly thinking about how to work with variables across App Domains. He mentioned there were two ways but that most people were only familiar with one.

I mentioned the volatile keyword (which, admittedly, I have never found a legitimate use for personally) and I also mentioned using locks, but he acted as though there was something else that you should do to declare a variable for use in multiple threads.

Anyone have any ideas what he may have been talking about?

Comment: If you got the job, wouldn't it be easier to just ask him what he actually meant because you got confused by him? :)

Comment: @Allan Yep, and I plan to just as soon as I start my first day.  But... I'm impatient and would like to know now, plus I'd rather find out whether I'm missing something or whether he's mistaken before I see him if possible! :)

Comment: I can't think of anything other than `volatile` may be he expected answer like *There is no such thing*

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I thought about that... and it definitely would have been a great trick question! He mentioned there were two ways though so I don't think he was trying to trick me.

Comment: Probably he was just fooling around with you..

Comment: @ShalinVed Thanks, it's sounding more and more like I answered correctly after all!

Comment: @BVernon Does the question is how to "declare variables..."? Or something else like how to make a field thread safe? because declaration doesn't makes a field thread safe.

Comment: Well, you are right not to use volatile at a whim it is hardly ever the right thing to do, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/06/16/atomicity-volatility-and-immutability-are-different-part-three.aspx. Locks or Interlocked operations would suffice. So, either the interviewer was alluding to this or he knows something other than volatile that very few other people do which sounds dangerous and best avoided for this reason alone. Post the answer when you know - will be interesting.

Comment: Could be he wanted you to go into a volatile vs. static discussion or similar, but we got to remember - interviewers can indeed be wrong as well :D

Comment: It really sounded like he was talking not about how to make the variable thread safe, but rather simply how to make it possible to even use it across threads. This is why I'm suspecting he may have really intended to ask about how to use them across App Domains. And so perhaps the 2 methods he was thinking of could have been inheriting from MarshalByRefObject and marking it Serializable. Of course those have to do with the class definition and not the variable declaration, but it's the closest thing I can think of that fits now.  Anyway, I will let you guys know what he says on Tuesday!

Answer (score 0):

The question shows that he does not know what he is talking about. If you want to use a variable across threads you do not have to do anything.

But maybe he was thinking of the Monitor class or read/write locks.

Or maybe he was thinking on how to pass the variable to a thread (parameterized threadstart delegate), but since anonymous methods and lambda expressions this is no longer an issue.